# Google home integration

Tags: mqtt, voice, google-home, home-automation

I would love some advise on how to make voice commands given to my Google home device be executed through my Mqtt server and my Node Red installation.  My mqtt broker and my node red is on a local raspberry pi placed safely behind my firewall.

I would love to avoid opening up for external internet traffic in my router.

I guess incoming http requests to node red could do the trick.  Or maybe the ha-bridge that emulate an older hue-bridge is the way to go. Or is it better to aim for the maker Chanel provided by ifttt?  Or is Dataplicity the way to go?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This question off topic for stackoverflow, but I have started work on a very similar node to my Alexa Home Skill node (http://alexa-node-red.bm.hardill.me.uk/) to work with Google Home. I'll publish it when I can get some time to finish it. Keep any eye on the Node-RED slack team for the best place to be notified

Comment: Thanks, hardillb.  I will follow slack team and look forward to you solution.  Thanks again.  There must be many more who would love a solution to this.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Googel Home -> IFTTT -> Adafruit.io MQTT -> node-red is what I've tested. Not happy that I cant go direct to a HA-Bridge or similar. From what ive seen any emulation (Philips Hue or Wemo) wont work now as you need to sign into that providers account.

Still prefer Alexa for this stuff, but Google home for music

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [gBridge.io](https://about.gbridge.io). It basically is exactly what you want: A service listening to commands from the Google services while sending/ receiving data from the user via MQTT